# Can rest API Response Code for custom error message be 400?

Tags: api, rest, response

In a restful API, what is the correct response code when responding with a custom error message? For example, "Username does not exist"

A colleague is arguing it should be code 400 and not 200

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error message, then the status is definitely not 200. It can be 4xx or 5xx depending on the cause. Here are a few possible status codes you can choose from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Answer (score 0):

> For example, "Username does not exist"

The correct answer is HTTP 404, the resource was not found.

https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/

Please note although you CAN include a String response in the body, that doesn't always mean you SHOULD. Some error messages can leak data useful to a malicious attacker. For example, say you get a JWT assertion from an internal tool called "CustomIDP" If you responded with the following.

```
CustomErrorException(status=401 UNAUTHORIZED, data="Missing the JWT token from CustomIDP, If you have issues call Jane Doe at ???-????-????)"
```

That was obviously a leak of internal information and it would have been better to just throw a 401 HTTP resopnse.